# Update nested document "acknowledged" : true but data not up to date as my operation

Tags: mongodb

```
/* post document 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5da832caeb173112348e509b"),//post._id
    "body" : "Lorem Ipsum .",
    "date" : ISODate("2019-10-17T09:21:45.452Z"),
    "comments" : [ 
        {
            "user" : "5d999578aeb073247de4bd6e",
            "comment" : "12345",
            "_id" : ObjectId("5db06e11d0987d0aa2cd5593"), //comments._id
            "replies" : [ 
                {
                    "likes" : [ 
                        "5d999578aeb073247de4bd6e", 
                        "5da85558886aee13e4e7f044"
                    ],
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5db6a88f7c6cfb0d0c2b689b"),
                    "reply" : "r11111111",
                    "user" : "5da85558886aee13e4e7f044"
                }
            ],
            "likes" : [ 
                "5da85558886aee13e4e7f044"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "likes" : [ 
        "5d999578aeb073247de4bd6e", 
        "5da85558886aee13e4e7f044"
    ]
}
```

My query to update `replies[i].likes`

db.getCollection("example").updateOne(

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5da832caeb173112348e509b"),
    "comments.replies": {
      "$elemMatch": {
        "_id": ObjectId("5db06e11d0987d0aa2cd5593"),//replies._id
      }
    }
  },
  { "$push": { "comments.$[outer].replies.$[inner].likes": "100000" } },
  {
    "arrayFilters": [
      { "outer._id": ObjectId("5db06e11d0987d0aa2cd5593") },//post._id
      { "inner._id": ObjectId("5db6a88f7c6cfb0d0c2b689b") }//comment._id
    ]
  }
)
```

I got the message after ran:

```
{
    "acknowledged" : true,
    "matchedCount" : 0.0,
    "modifiedCount" : 0.0
}
```

but collection is not updated , what is wrong with my query?

Comment: Are you not receive update data or not update in collection ??

Comment: data is still the same, I mean not update in collection, sorry with english

Comment: "comments.replies._id": objectId() use

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, can give the full answer? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query

```
db.getCollection("example").updateOne(

{
    "_id": ObjectId("5da832caeb173112348e509b"),
    "comments.replies._id":ObjectId("5db6a88f7c6cfb0d0c2b689b"),//replies._id
  },
  { "$push": { "comments.$[outer].replies.$[inner].likes": "100000" } },
  {
    "arrayFilters": [
      { "outer._id": ObjectId("5db06e11d0987d0aa2cd5593") },//post._id
      { "inner._id": ObjectId("5db6a88f7c6cfb0d0c2b689b") }//comment._id
    ]
  }
)
```

Comment: collection not update, and return this msg to me : `{
    "acknowledged" : true,
    "matchedCount" : 0.0,
    "modifiedCount" : 0.0
}`

Comment: Please now use that code

Comment: thank you so much, it works. can you help to explain .

Comment: Use update _id is wrong so not updated

Comment: what is the difference  "5da832caeb173112348e509b" instead of ObjectId("5da832caeb173112348e509b")

Comment: _id field is not string data type. _id field is objectId data type.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201634/discussion-between-mahesh-bhatnagar-and-kn3l).